# How to select duplicate lines from a data frame?

Tags: r

I have something like this:

```
df <- data.frame('C1' = c("A","A","C","D","E","E","E"), 'C2' = c("B1","B2","B3","B1","B1","B2","B4"))
```

And I would like something like that:

```
C1  C2
A   B1
A   B2
E   B1
E   B2
E   B4
```

Then I would like something like that:

```
B1 B2 2  (because A and E)
B1 B4 1  (because only E)
B2 B4 1  (because only E)
```

Comment: Use `duplicated` to get the duplicated rows: `df[ duplicated(df$C1) | duplicated(df$C1,fromLast = T), ]`

Comment: The comment above answers the question in the title but I don't think the questions was expressed clearly. I'm unable to see what I would call a "duplicate line" in the data. What sort of pairing is supposed to be done to get B1-B4 and B2-B4 pairs as indicated in the desired answer?

Comment: It seems that the expected result comes from creating all two-pair combinations of `C2` within the same `C1` and then counting how many are there in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  full_join(df, by = 'C1') %>%
  filter(!C2.x == C2.y, 
         !gsub("\\D", "", C2.y) < gsub("\\D", "", C2.x)
         ) %>%
  count(Combination = paste(C2.x, C2.y))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Combination     n
  <chr>       <int>
1 B1 B2           2
2 B1 B4           1
3 B2 B4           1
```

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` approach could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(C1) %>%
 filter(n() >= 2) %>%
 mutate(C3 = list(combn(C2, 2, FUN = paste, collapse = ","))) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 unnest(C3) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 count(C3)

  C3        n
  <chr> <int>
1 B1,B2     2
2 B1,B4     1
3 B2,B4     1
```

First, it filters out cases from C1 with only one observation. Then, it combines every two elements from C2 per group. Finally, it counts the number of appearances per pair.

Considering there could be duplicated C2 values per group:

```
df %>%
 group_by(C1) %>%
 filter(n() >= 2) %>%
 mutate(C3 = list(combn(unique(C2), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = ",")))  %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 unnest(C3) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 count(C3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use dplyr and data.table libraries

```
install.package("tidyverse")
install.package("data.table")

library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)


df2 = df %>%
  filter(C1 %in% c('A', 'E'))
```